# why does argument value change in nested call and lead to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, visual-studio, segmentation-fault, android-ndk, porting

I have Visual Studio project which I am porting to android. I am facing a problem of segmentation fault in function calls which resembles the functions below:

```
char* format1(const char* fmt, ...) {
    char* buf = new char[1030];
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return buf;
}

char* format2(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    char* s = format1(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return s;
}
```

The call to the functions is as below:

```
char* s = format2("%*.*d", 8, 8, 9910153);
```

I have a couple of queries regarding the above:

If I step through the code in gdb for the call to 'function2' it shows:
format (fmt=0x4 )
Why is this so?

When 'function1' gets called gdb shows:
format1 (fmt=0x15be30 "some random value in memory")
How come the value of fmt has changed? Also, depending on the value in fmt the second call leads to segmentation fault.

Any help in explaining the above behavior would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just pass `ap` as a `va_list` or use `va_arg` to extract it.

Answer (score 3):

`format1` takes a variadic set of arguments, not a `va_list`; you pass a single (non-integer) argument to it, and the format string expects three integer arguments, so undefined behaviour ensues.

It should be something like:

```
char* format1(const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
    char* buf = new char[1030];
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, ap);    
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which asked why the debugger reports fmt=0x4. The undefined behavior of `vsnprintf` can't cause that because the function hasn't been called yet.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I'm answering the question in the title: why is there a segfault? I've no idea exactly how a particular debugger might behave in the presence of stack corruption.

Comment: Upon entry to `format2` (and indeed, even upon entry to `format1`), no stack corruption has happened yet. That doesn't happen until `vsnprintf` gets called.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks, I overlooked the argument definition (case of sloppy copy+paste). But the display of gdb is really confusing becuase it's display kept diverting my attention! Any explanation for the display by gdb? Should I pose it as a different question?